# Overseas fund transfer by certified check

Tags: money-transfer, international-transfer, wire-transfer

I work as a freelance web developer/designer residing in India. Recently I finalized a deal with a client in Jacksonville, FL for a web design contract which involves a weekly payment.

The problem is the client is ready to make payments only via certified check. What I look for is the most convenient way for the client to transfer the funds, and am ready to bear any costs related to the transfer no matter how high they are.

I already have a PayPal account in place, but the client insists only on check payment.

Comment: Not sure why you are spooked about a certified check. It is as safe if not more than a Paypal account. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_check

Comment: Thank you for your info, however I still have some further questions

1. the clients asks to provide my address with my PO Box number, does entering an international address still make the same work?
2. Suppose it does work, and he manages to courier it to me, will I be able to cash it directly?

Comment: So whats the problem to deposit a check?

Comment: @littleadv , well to be frank I am not sure how the procedure works, is my client actually allowed to write me a check considering the overseas factor?

Comment: @dylan - Do you have a bank account? Is there a local office to walk into and talk to someone? If so, go in and ask, "I am doing work for a company in the US, and they will send me a certified check. How long will it take the funds to clear?" Their answer will put your mind at ease more that we can.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Yep, did have a talk with my bank and they informed me that they do accept overseas checks, only issue being that the client will now have to courier me the check.

Also, apparently clearing such checks takes a whopping 21 days. Let's see what my client has to say to that. Will convince them to rather do a direct wire transfer which takes 5-7 days.

thanks to all for your kind help!

Comment: @dylan - glad if I helped. I'm surprised they said a wire takes so long. I am in the US, and wired money to a store in Hong Kong that I'd visited years prior. They acknowledged the funds two days later.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Wiring money to India does indeed take 5-7 business days if the inexpensive service provided by many Indian banks is used: 5 days if the recipient's account is in the same bank as is providing the wire transfer service, 7 if the recipient's account is in a different bank. Most Indian banks also provide a "Power Transfer" or "Express Transfer" service which works in 2 days, but is a _lot_ more expensive (e.g. $2 vs $35 for amounts under $10K).

Answer (score 2):

The terms of payments are agreement between you and your client. See how best you want to negotiate.

Checks depending on how you clients post them, would take around 5-7 days to reach you. There is additional paperwork you need to complete to encash the USD Check. If you deposit the check in a local non-metro city, it would take close to 30 to 45 days. Ideally mail it directly to a branch in metro city. It typically takes around 21 - 30 days. You would still be charged a fee although less than a Wire.

Wire transfers are faster but expensive ... you can also explore Remittance solution that are offered by several banks in US [Citi, HDFC, ICICI, etc]. These cost less than a wire.